# Почему onBackPressed() закрывает приложение?

Tags: java, android

Есть кнопка, которая якобы должна возвращать на предыдущее активи, но вместо этого - она закрывает все приложение сразу. В чем проблема?

**FirstActivity**

```
public void onClickStart(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

**SecondActivity**

```
public void onClickBack(View view) {
        onBackPressed();
    }
```

**AndroidManifest**

```
<activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name=".FirstActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name=".SecondActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
```

Comment: Не нужно вызывать методы колбэков явно, они не так работают. Вместо этого вызовите `finish()`

Comment: А при вызове `this.onBackPressed();` происходит то же самое?

Comment: Покажите как указали эти активности в манифесте

Comment: При вызове this.onBackPressed(); происходит то же самое. Активити, на которое хочу вернуться, не описано в манифесте как стартовое. Стартовое активити - SplashScreen, которое через n-ый промежуток времени уничтожается

Comment: А как Вы осуществляете переход с `SplashScreen` на главное активити? Возможно Вы при переходе удаляете `SplashScreen` из стэка, поэтому при попытке перейти обратно из `MainActivity` приложение закрывается, т.к. ему некуда переходить)

Comment: @Denis422 , вероятнее всего

Answer (score 1):

Возможно,

```
onBackPressed();
```

вообще не нужно вызывать.

Если это не поможет, попробуйте сделать finish()

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно вернуться на предыдущее `Activity` и закрыть текущее, используй `finish();`